# createElement() vs AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login form and after the user logs in the page will be updated with user data via AJAX and the login form will be deleted via JavaScript so I don't have non semantic DOM elements in my page. 
My problem is that after the user logs out the form will be displayed again. 
Is it a better practice to create all the elements via JavaScript or perform an AJAX request to server and out put the data?
The form will have only a username and password field.

Comment: It is personal opinion. People will say, X, others Y, and others Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should use depends on you want to do next.

Using client side DOM creation is preferable when you want your server-side to be environment-independent.

Will you use your server side code for multiple platforms like building a mobile app?

Will you have multiple entry points where the user can login so that they can have different HTML markup?

If yes, it shouldn't return HTML code but rather JSON or XML or anything similar.

If you don't plan any of this and you wan't just a simple website with little  maintenance, returning HTML is the easier way to go. When all your server-side code is returning HTML, there is no reason why you should bother using client-side templates just for one form as you would have to keep track of two different places where your markup is.